# How to check CGWindowID still valid

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

If I am getting a CGWindowID (_windowID) as follows...

```
NSArray *windowList = (__bridge NSArray *)CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
for (NSDictionary *info in windowList) { 
    if ([[info objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGWindowOwnerName] isEqualToString:@"window name"] && ![[info objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGWindowName] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        _windowID = [[info objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGWindowNumber] unsignedIntValue];
    }
}
```

How do I properly test the window id is still valid and the window has not been closed? Do i just run similar code just checking window id exists?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the `kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly` constant says:

> **List all windows that are currently onscreen**. Windows are returned in
>   order from front to back. When retrieving a list with this option, the
>   relativeToWindow parameter should be set to kCGNullWindowID.

So the windows would certainly be on screen, since nothing appears to be happening between the call to `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` and your action on it.

Maybe you'd want to test to make sure they are not hidden or minimized?

Comment: The window in question I'm capturing can't be hidden or minimised of such. I really just after checking since I got the window id if the window has now been closed.

Comment: If a window were closed, it probably wouldn't even appear in the `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`-generated list of windows when passing the `kCGWindowListOptionAll` (i.e. onscreen & offscreen) parameter.

Comment: Indeed I was just wondering if there was a quicker method than just getting the list of window Id's again, and seeing if window is still in list. At moment as a hack since I'm  screen capturing the window I check if window size is 1x1 and if so assume its been closed.

Comment: You can also designate some object as a window delegate, so you can catch whenever a window is closed via the delegate's [`windowWillClose:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowWillClose:).